# How to store and access generated data in a project?

Tags: python, animation-nodes, data-blocks

I have written some code to work in conjunction with Animation Nodes to use MIDI files to drive procedural animations. It works wonderfully, but I want to refactor and polish it before I release it. The main thing I wanted to change is to take the original MIDI data and convert it to a format that's preprocessed and more easily navigable since MIDI is a streaming file structure (it can only go forwards, if you want to go backwards you have to start from the beginning). 
So to the heart of the question: How can I store and access the generated file in the .blend so my addon can use it without reading external files?

Answer (score 1):

**Keyframes**

Suggest using your midi file reader to keyframe the animation. I have done this using the very basic [pysmf reader](https://github.com/dsacre/pysmf) to make an action of custom properties for each track. For example in image below "AE" for electric guitar track, and "AB" for muted trumpet track.

For each of the midi notes in the track, if there is an ON event, keyframe that to a custom property, eg middle C on electric guitar "AE" would be assigned custom property AE60.  The `smf` decoder gives middle C as C4, I get it's midi position 60 by finding its index in `midi_notes` list below. Your reader may handle this differently.

```
notes = ['C', 'C#', 'D', 'D#', 'E', 'F', 'F#', 'G', 'G#', 'A', 'A#', 'B']
octaves = range(-1, 10)

midi_notes = ["%s%d" % (n, o) for o in octaves for n in notes]
#pop off the last 4

for i in range(4):
midi_notes.pop()
```

*Rather than using custom properties, `ob["AE60"]`, another method would be to create collection property for the tracks and channels.*

The velocity and event time in seconds, converted to frame, of each on / off note event in the track, are keyframed as a `(frame, value)` pair.  Constant interpolation will make the note stay on until an off event.

To find the value of AE60 in an action named "MidiAction" at frame 44

```
bpy.data.actions["MidiAction"].fcurves.find('["AE60"]').evaluate(44)
```

[image]

The very much WIP code to produce action [above is here](https://github.com/batFINGER/batFINGER-blender-addons/blob/cdf60b151b546752d47ade588f07dae3acc36c2b/sound_drivers/midi.py#L174)