# Live MIDI input for EEVEE

Tags: python, node-editor, eevee-render-engine

I want to write a python script that will allow for a CDJ's Pro Link midi file to get converted into animation modifiers. The goal is to have the midi data's key and tempo to effect some variables, where the intensity or loudness affect the others. I have been searching all over online for how to do something like this, but no luck. If anyone has any idea how to do this, please let me know.

Comment: Have voted to close this as too broad.  Addons are written in python 3.  Midi file format is a standard (not just for CDJ prolink).  There are a number of 3rd party python midi modules to choose from, from the lightweight `smf` to the full blown `pymidi` to read the midi file or stream the IO.  [Searching this site for `midi`](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=midi) produces plenty of results.  [Here is an example of mine re creating actions from midi using `smf`](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/103043/15543)

Comment: @batFINGER thank you! I was not aware, I shall do my research!